# N elements list of string validation in cerberus

Tags: python, string, list, validation, cerberus

How can I validate that certain type is a list and it contains only e.g string elements, of unknown number?

My current solution is

```
'categories_id' : {'required' : False, 'type' : ['string','list']},
```

but it doesn't do the trick, is also returns `True` when you supply just a single string, not in a list.

Answer (score 1):

The schema mentioned in the question `'categories_id' : {'required' : False, 'type' : ['string','list']}` makes Cerberus check `categories_id` field is either a string or a list. So a single string will return true.

To make Cerberus check that `categories_id` is a list of strings with any number of items, following schema should be used

`{'categories_id': {'required': False, 'type': 'list', 'schema': {'type': 'string'}}}`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do that using `cerberus`, but it should be pretty simple without any modules:

```
def validate(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return all(isinstance(I, str) for i in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`valuesrules`](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#valuesrules)

```py
>>> schema = {'categories_id':
...              {'type': 'list',
...               'valuesrules': {'type': 'string'}}}
```